# What is the flow that happens when submitting the form on a cloud page using Axios/ajax?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, cloudpage

I am trying to implement the solution given by [this website](https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/how-to-start-status-of-automation-from-marketingcloud-form/?unapproved=474&moderation-hash=99c95f431503957cdb187cdab491c986#comment-474), to start an automation from a cloud page.

There are 3 parts of code.

1. HTML page (understood this)
2. form-handler code with SSJS (understood this)
3. app.js (did not understand this)

I am not able to understand the overall flow. On submit of the form, I get that the data is posted to a form-handler. Then I am not able to understand how app.js plays its part between HTML & form handler.

Can anyone help me crack the logic behind this setup?

Answer (score 0):

The `app.js` file encapsulates all the **client-side** JavaScript logic during form submission:

- Validating form input
- Sending requests/data to the server-side resource (e.g., the SSJS handler)
- Handling the server-side resource's response to a request (e.g., updating an HTML element — `<span v-html="message"></span>` — with the latest status)
- Continuing to poll the server-side resource at a set interval *in the background* — this is where Axios helps

In the article you linked to, the Vue.js JavaScript framework was used, but the same logic can be implemented using any other UI library/framework (e.g., React, Angular, Svelte, etc.) or even plain/vanilla JavaScript (although more verbose).

Why use client-side JavaScript at all in this scenario? It allows you to kick-off an automation with a single click and watch its current status update without having to manually refresh/resubmit the HTML form (thanks to Axios/AJAX).